# Running safari from webdriver

Tags: safari, webdriver

I'm trying to run Safari from WebDriver. When i start the project it cant build beacouse it cannot find safari. Safari is installed on the machine, i am registered as an developer.

Does anyone have a solution?

Code:

```
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
    }
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplore")) {
        capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capability.setBrowserName("iexplore");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
    }
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
    }
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari")) {
        capability = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
        capability.setBrowserName("safari");
        capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
    }

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    driver.navigate().to(test_data.BASE_URL);
```

Stacktrace:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup("safari")
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=ANY, browserName=safari, version=}
Command duration or timeout: 203 milliseconds
```

Comment: It's still experimental, but take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The new version of selenium i.e. **selenium 2.30.0** is released.Grab it as it has built in support for safari driver...Enjoy!!!